# single host multi container v.s. multi host single container

Tags: docker

Would a single host machine running multiple containers (app, db, webserver) be more efficient than multiple host machines (in the same LAN) running a single container?

Efficient being defined as hardware costs and speed of the server. Imagine this particular app has a thousand GETs per day, with a few hundred POSTs.

Comment: I think the question is too general to get a definite answer. It all depends on how much resources your containers consume and how they communicate with each other.

Comment: I agree that it is a general question (hard to search for on google.) Imagine I have a VM environment, so I have 18 CPU's, 32GB of RAM, and X amount of HD. Say my DB server needs 8 CPU's and 16GB of RAM, and the app/web server need the rest. Is it better to use Docker's ability to allocate X amount of resources per container on a single host, or is it better to have multiple hosts?

Comment: Several hosts cannot run a **single** container. According to the CaaS (Container as a Service) best practice one container should run one process. So your question, according to the best practice, become: "Is it better to run a multi-container app on a single host or a single container app on multi hosts?" But then, I wonder how a **single process** can run on several hosts.

Comment: @Auzias I know this is too late to comment it here. But i 'm really curious to ask.. Is there any way to do that (Running a single container over multiple machines) ?. If you wish, please leave the possible ways as comments.  : )

Comment: Do you mean "the same container [0] that is a single-process-container" running on several hosts ([0] : not image, **container**) ? If so, can you explain me how to deal with this kind of "single process" without docker please.